# video chatting in WebGL

Tags: video-streaming, chat, webgl, vnc, linden-scripting-language

I would like to develop a virtual classroom contains projector for presenting power point's slides and video chatting.all these tools will be developed using WebGL.
Is there any possibility for including video chatting, and presenting power point's slides "Using VNC applets" inside my project.

Comment: please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7116631/edit) to provide more information. also, you have never accepted an answer to [any of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831848/abdulkareem?tab=questions),

Answer (score 3):

There is some active work by Google and others to add [WebRTC](http://webrtc.org) as a standardized web API for doing peer-to-peer chat.

For VNC, you can check out [noVNC](http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) which is an HTML5 (Canvas, WebSockets) VNC client. (Disclaimer: I made noVNC)

**Update:**

You can use video and canvas data as your textures in WebGL and I expect that this will be true of WebRTC data also. Mozilla has a tutorial [Animating textures in WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/webgl/animating_textures_in_webgl) about drawing video from a video tag into WebGL. The same mechanism can be used for canvas (e.g. noVNC).

Comment: thanks a lot ...

But my question is about how i can include these tools inside the 3D virtual classroom?

Comment: @Abdulkareem, I added an update with an answer to your question.